# How to create a div with an irregular shape?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to create a `div` with an irregular shape with CSS? I already searched but I can't find a good example. The style is something like this:

```
              /
             /                     \
            /                       \
           /                         \
          /___________________________\
```

There **should be a line on the top** that connects it. Basically it has different height on the left and right side.

Comment: check the following link it contains code for creating different types of shapes using css.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

i hope this might help you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**THE SVG WAY**

Since the shape you request is not possible with only CSS, I suggest you use SVG to draw the shape.

The following piece of code will create the below shape:

```html
<svg height="150" width="150">
    <polygon points="20,10 100,30 120,100 0,100" style="fill:red;" />
</svg>
```

[image: Irregular trapezoid shape]

SVG is a powerful tool to make shapes otherwise impossible without using images. Read up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

---

**HTML & CSS Answer**

This can be done by using `perspective` and `transform`. You create two divs: one that will get the `perspective` and one that will be transformed. Just know that anything in the `.test`-div will also be transformed, so if you put text in there, it will also get transformed.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    perspective: 150px;
}

.test {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a517sb5m/)**

Comment: Just click on the Fiddle link in the bottom to see the code. I've added a border to the wrapper, so you can actually see the perspective: http://jsfiddle.net/a517sb5m/1/

Answer (score 11):

This can also be done using CSS [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 10%, 85% 30%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 10%, 85% 30%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can then just change the background element if you need an image.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(https://lorempixel.com/200/150/);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 10%, 85% 30%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 10%, 85% 30%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

In their current state, clip-paths aren't as widely supported as inline or imported SVG but is a much cleaner, and in some cases, easier variant to use.

- [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using overflow hidden and transforms, though the best approach will be svg.

HTML

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="in"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { background:url(http://www.placecage.com/g/640/480) }
.out {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.in {
    height: 110px;
    width: 148px;
    position: relative;
    left: -43px;
    top: -7px;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: skew(30deg) rotate(10deg);
    background: rgba(9,40,0,0.8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.in:hover {
    background: rgba(50,0,70,0.7);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

**FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/xb1jxd7g/**

Comment: It would be better adding a `backface-visibility: hidden;` to the `.out` to smooth the jagged edges (or you could also add a null transform ` translateZ(0)` to the transform stack) :)

Answer (score -2):

Following it for diamond and make a way around to rotate it and you'll get your shape :

```
#diamond-shield {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid red;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}

#diamond-shield:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px; top: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 70px solid red;
}
```